# Not able to fetch all rows of data from MS SQL Server using RODBC even with believeNRows=F

Tags: sql-server, r, pyodbc, rodbc

I am trying to use `RODBC` library in R to fetech data from Microsoft SQL Server through a query, but the data I got is incomplete even if I set `believeNRows=FALSE`. The Microsoft SQL Server version is `SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU3`

The R code is as following:

```
library(RODBC)
sql.server = 'GDCSCTDDBSWA01'
database.name = 'Data.Analytics'
sql.string = 'select * from [Data.Analytics].[dbo].[Table]'
db.string <- sprintf("driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}; server=%s;database={%s}; trusted_connection=yes", server , database.name)
db.channel <- odbcDriverConnect(db.string, believeNRows=FALSE)
itin.data <- data.table(sqlQuery(db.channel, sql.string))
close(db.channel)
```

It only returned around 1500 rows of data (the exact number of rows changes in each run, but it is around the same magnitude). However, when I ran the query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, it worked correctly.

To eliminate the possibility of network issue, I also tried `pyodbc` and it also worked fine. The python code is as following:

```
import pyodbc
connection= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=GDCSCTDDBSWA01;DATABASE={Data.Analytics};trusted_connection=yes')
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = 'select * from [Data.Analytics].[dbo].[Table]'
cursor.execute(sql)
dataList = cursor.fetchall()
connection.close()
```

Does anyone have an idea what causes `RODBC` to fail?

Comment: Whats error you are getting?

Comment: No run-time error is given. But when checking the number of row in the result, I can see it is incorrect.

Comment: Is your R code returning 100 rows? The *really bad decision* was made to default `odbcConnect` to only return the first 100 rows at a time. Settings `rows_at_time=999999999` is an ugly solution... but may work. See page 5 of this PDF: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf (PDF as the default form of docs... another *really bad decision*).

Comment: It is returning around 1500 rows and the number changes in each run. I actually tried `db.channel <- odbcDriverConnect(db.string, believeNRows=FALSE, rows_at_time = 5000)`, but amazingly nothing changes.

Comment: I agree with FlipperPA that those were design decisions I question; regardless, are you boxed into `RODBC`, or are you able to shift to [`RSQLServer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLServer/index.html)? I've been using it for some time with no such symptoms (and ~2M rows at a time).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. I can try `RSQLServer` later. I am using `RODBC` since it is the one I used for a while.

Comment: Hi, have u resolved this problem? I have the same and I can't find any other information

Answer (score 0):

Setting `believeNRows = FALSE` in the sqlQuery statement should pull all rows.

```
sqlQuery(myconn, "select * from table", believeNRows = FALSE)
```